# Checking active date in last six months

Tags: sql

Hi I have table of temp who works at our company. Table has start date and End date. I need to find out all temps who were active in last six months.

Table like below
TEMPID     STARTDATE    ENDDATE 
1          `(ENDDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())
OR (ENDDATE  = '1900-01-01'
AND STARTDATE <= GETDATE())`
2
3
I am trying like this

SO basically I am looking only active jobs in last six months but by putting this condition it shows all recored who were avtive evan before

Comment: Tag your question with the databse you are using.

Comment: You have `'1900-01-01'`, a pretty *low* value, as indicator for *positive infinity*? What's wrong with `NULL` or at least something like `'9999-12-31'` (or whatever the highest possible value is).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you're asking to filter by start date so leave that out of the query. I'm assuming you're using '1900-01-01' in place of a `NULL` value to indicate an employee is still active.

... `WHERE (ENDDATE='1900-01-01' OR ENDDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())`

If you just want people who were hired within the past 6 months, you could add `AND STARDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks Chris for answering. Is it possible to put condition only on END date . If someone was active in last six months. I am bit confused how I do this.

Comment: Yes, that was the first bit: `WHERE (ENDDATE='1900-01-01' OR ENDDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())` -- This is only using the END date to determine if someone had been _dismissed_ in the past 6 months, or their end date was set to 1900-01-01 (again I'm assuming here that this means they're still working,) therefore they _were_ active in the past 6 months..